# Moment Question

Tags: integration, centroid

I am looking for feedback on some points actually. I am looking at the centroid equation $\frac{\int x f(x) dx}{\int f(x) dx}$, assuming that the integrals are bounded, will not consider constants.

I was trying to see if I can simplify this a little bit by considering opening the numerator by parts.

So one version of the numerator would be $$x \int f(x) dx - \int\int f(x) dx dx$$

other $$\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 f(x) - f'(x) + f''(x)+ \dots \right)$$

Any idea is this can be simplified

Comment: Why is $\int xf(x)dx=x\int f(x) dx-\iint f(x)dxdx$? Indeed, "dx dx" is quite meaningless

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree. If $\int u dv = u v-\int v du$ and we put $u=x$ and $dv=f(x)$, v would become $\int f(x) dx$. the $\int v du$ part is would result in integrating $f(x)$ twice. I agree it is meaningless, and i do not know how to represent it to be honest

Comment: I just don’t think the formula can be simplified without further knowledge of the shape or of $f$